# How much did the RM 380Z weigh?

Tags: hardware, british-computers, rm

The Research Machines 380Z was an early British microcomputer, released in 1977. Unlike many other early microcomputers, the design was industrial style, a hefty metal box, sometimes described as 'built like a tank'; a good description can be found here: https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/658229301760799838/

It is said to be rack mountable, though the width has been given at 59.5 cm, which is 23.4 inches; I thought a standard equipment rack was 19 inches wide?

One thing I have not been able to find is a figure for the weight of the machine. I imagine it must've been quite substantial, and not necessarily easy to carry with those thin handles.

How much did it weigh?

Comment: 23 inch racks were used for telephone equipment and, apparently, the Manchester Baby (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19-inch_rack#23-inch_rack).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Machines_380Z indicates it was in a 19 inch rack mount.

Comment: Sorry, just learned that my [bathroom scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcoE4.jpg) battery went dead. A rough comparison with a beer case gives a similar weight, so somewhere around 15 to 20 kg (without keyboard, which is at least another 2-3 kg). I may try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It is said to be rack mountable, though the width has been given at 59.5 cm, which is 23.4 inches; I thought a standard equipment rack was 19 inches wide?

Not really. It's a bit wider than 49 cm or 19 inches (*1) as shown here:

[image]

So it's safe to assume that the 59.5 you found might have been a typo and should rather read 49.5.

> One thing I have not been able to find is a figure for the weight of the machine. I imagine it must've been quite substantial,

While I can't answer the weight part exactly due a [dead battery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcoE4.jpg), I did a quick comparison with a beer case (17 kg) and it did feel rather similar. Plus at least another ~2 kg for the keyboard :)

<s>More as soon as I get a working scale.</s> Only 4 month later I got that darn beast working:

The **system unit wights 15.2 kg** (ca. 33 1/3 foot-stones or whatever that is called) plus the **keyboard** adding an astonishing **4.2 kg**.

> and not necessarily easy to carry with those thin handles.

Oh, they are, like with any 19 inch, really helpful and make moving it rather easy. It's the boxy shape that gets into one's way. Carrying two helps, one in each hand to balance them out.

---

*1 - Yes, I own a tape measure with inches. I got it a few weeks ago in England, they still have them.

Comment: Here in Canada, our tape measures also have both metric and feet/inches, because the U.S. is such a big customer for our lumber industry that we cut to their measurements.

Comment: @ssokolow Well, it was just meant to poke a bit fun of them, but yeah, lumber is an interesting area even here certain sizes are still deep down based on old sizes. For example basic batten size is 24x36 mm roughly 1"x1.5" when including the blade size. Regarding England, I need to be fair as they really made the move by now almost universal - with the exception of road signs that is.

Comment: It'll come in handy for measuring DEC memory boards...

Comment: @Raffzahn Milk and beer can still be bought in pints.

Comment: @Neil Last time (two weeks ago) I visited a Tesco, it had everything marked in liter - even the pints (0,568l) :))

Comment: @Raffzahn I have a 1 pint bottle of Tesco milk in my fridge, but yes, it is labelled in ml *as well*. By comparison, I buy 907g packs of frozen peas - no mention of the fact that it's 2lb.

Comment: @Neil not really, a two pound would be 1000g - at least over here.

Comment: @Raffzahn FYI an Imperial pound is a mass of approximately 453.5g.

Comment: @Neil Well, and a Bavarian one is ~560, while a Prussian pound is 467, while the customs pound is 500, so go figure.

Comment: @Raffzahn Bavarian pounds are not used in the UK... Neil is correct, but don't confuse the imperial measurements with US ones - an English Gallon contains 8 pints, the American gallon short changes us on beer...

Comment: @SolarMike Nor are imperial pounds. But, yeah, I know that feeling well. A Bavarian Maß had 1,07 liter (50 cubic inch), a metric one only 1l. They changed it about 150 years ago, but we still suffer ...